# Select row-index value by span text

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, webdriver-io

how can I make a selector or an algorithm to return the row-index value with the text of a span?

Html code:

```html
<div class="container">
<div row-index="0">
   <div>
      <div>
         <span>
            <div>
               <span>
               Test1234
               </span>
            </div>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div row-index="1">
   <div>
      <div>
         <span>
            <div>
               <span>
               1234test
               </span>
            </div>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Expected result: getIndex("1234test"); //will return 1 because row-index='1'

Everything I tried did not help me get to the final solution, will you be able to suggest a solution or give me some advice? I really don't even know where to start

Comment: In what context are you trying to determine the row-index?  For example, are you attempting to find the row-index as a result of an event (such as onclick)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the easiest way is to use `xpath` to solve the problem.

Let's create a function for that:

```js
async function getRowIndexBy(text) {
  const element = await $(`.//span[normalize-space()='${text}']/ancestor::div[@row-index]`);

  return element.getAttribute('row-index');
}
```

Usage:

```js
await getRowIndexBy('1234test'); // will return '1'
```

This function will find the grandparent element (it's `div` with `row-index` attribute in your case) of the element that was found by text (`span` in your case) and will return the value of the `row-index` attribute.

Tested against provided HTML:

[image: Worked on your HTML]